# How to use If condition in Button intent call?

Tags: java, android

I have created two activities:

1. Play
2. MorpionAI

decide and checkedplayer are both some integers.

How can I make my app so that when the button is clicked the app selects and calls one of the intents based on following:

```
if(decide==checkedplayer){
    public void MorpionAI_Acitivity(View view) {
        Clean();
        deleteplayer();
        Intent play = new Intent(this, MorpionAI.class);
        startActivity(play);
    }}
else{
    public void Play_Activity(View view) {
    Clean();
    deleteplayer();
    Intent play = new Intent(this, Play.class);
    startActivity(play);
    }}
```

I tried to do this using following code:

```
morpionbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (decide==checkedplayer){
            Clean();
            deleteplayer();

            Intent play = new Intent(view.getContext(), Play.class);
            startActivity(play);
        }
        else{
            Clean();
            deleteplayer();

            Intent play = new Intent(view.getContext(), MorpionAI.class);
            startActivity(play);
        }
    }
});
```

But it did not worked.

Comment: Is there a way by which I can call an Activity(View view) inside a method?

Comment: Where is the morpion button ? In aCtivity, fragment, ... ?

Comment: it is displayed on main activity layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your activity , defined a `Context` class field :

```
private Context mContext;
```

in the `onCreate()` function of this activity , initialize the field :

```
mContext = this;
```

then

```
morpionbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (decide == checkedplayer){
            Clean();
            deleteplayer();

            Intent play = new Intent(mContext, Play.class);
            mContext.startActivity(play);
        }
        else {
            Clean();
            deleteplayer();

            Intent play = new Intent(mContext, MorpionAI.class);
            mContext.startActivity(play);
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.